# Elasticsearch DSL Query for displaying elements based on field value in multiple documents

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl

How can I perform a select query similar to the below in elastic search assuming each row in the table is a separate document ?

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
  `orderid` varchar,
  `status` varchar
);

insert into orders values('abc','PENDING');
insert into orders values('abc','SENT');
insert into orders values('xyz','PENDING');

select * from orders where status='PENDING' and orderid not in (select orderid from orders where status='SENT')
```

Comment: Instead of updating status for a given order id why there is a requirement to insert a new row each time status for a orderId changes.

Comment: I insert a new document in elastic search to have a snapshot at any point in time. These are log messages that I’m streaming to elastic search from my application and it will be used for analytics

Comment: The query you require is not possible in elastic

Answer (score 0):

From the SQL query what I understand is you need all records which have status = "PENDING" . Not sure why you need the AND condition here for excluding the orders with status="SENT" as status="pending" will get you the required rows.

Now, coming to the elastic query, assuming the status field is a keyword field you can use bool queries to get the documents with status -"pending" 
Something like this -

```
{
 "query": {
   "bool": {
      "must": [
         {
           "term":{
             "status.keyword":"PENDING"
           }
         }
      ]
   }
 }
}
```

In case you need to find all documents with status pending and sent both (AND condition) add another term query inside the must clause above.
if the statuses need to be OR-ed then put the term queries inside a should clause (inside the bool query) and set minimum_should_match parameter to 1.
In case you need all values in a given time frame, add a filter to the bool with the time range query inside.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. If I apply this on the above example , I guess I will get both the “pending” records. But I just need “xyz” because the latest state of abc is “sent”.

Comment: ok, now I understand your use case , actually in the SQL query,I assumed that orderId is the auto generated primary key which will be different for all rows, but what you want to exclude is orders which have already been completed ("SENT") .Right off the bat, what I can think of is you can use two queries, the first one returns the list of all orderids which are completed and then put them in a must_not clause to exclude those from the PENDING orders list.This is because ES doesn't support sub-queries like mysql.

Comment: You can take a look at this elasticsearch plugin which adds an SQL layer on top of ES - https://github.com/opendistro-for-elasticsearch/sql